# Should all cultures be maintained?

Tags: rights, human-rights, philosophy-of-culture

I think Chomsky has argued that no states have the right to exist. What about cultures?

Some cultures practised human sacrifice: if they existed now, should the culture be preserved completely, in part or not at all?

For the sake of argument, allow that the culture is not harmful, in that it has a net benefit to those in and outside it. Should that culture be preserved, as a moral or amoral absolute?

Comment: i don't have an opinion on this really. on the one hand, ways of life are very important things; on the other hand, idt that all cultures are equal (not because some are high and others low, but because some allow for humanity better)

Comment: Seems a bit difficult to answer . . . you mention human sacrifice (so I assume the Aztecs), but then dial it down drastically. What's the emphasis here? Are you concerned with if its a moral *absolute* or a *moral* absolute?

Comment: if it was very easy to answer i wouldn't have bothered asking it @Hokon the emphasis is on "*right* to exist", if that is absolute, whether or not it's "moral"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Let me ponder this and I may attempt an answer (hopefully better thought-out than the last answer I posted to another question of yours!).

Comment: i hope the question makes enough sense and welcome any reply @Hokon can't find any answers to me, what did you have in mind? good luck

Comment: it's less that i think it's a good question, than i wanted to think about the question more clearly

Comment: Good motivation! I'm pondering invoking Scheler, since he has a rather unique and underappreciated view of culture. But, my work in recent years doesn't involve those parts of his philosophy. I'll want to do some re-reading before posting an answer. Also not sure if I should post such a "narrow" answer though (i.e., one philosopher's perspective).

Comment: sounds good. all i have is google @Hokon which tells me that husserl thought all cultures have a right to exist but some more than others (i gloss sightly) ha

Comment: Does *the fact that Dave likes spaghetti* have a right to exist? If Dave stops liking spaghetti, has he violated the rights of an abstract concept? Should we threaten to shoot Dave if he won't like spaghetti, or maybe find somebody else and threaten to shoot them if they won't name their children Dave and raise them to like spaghetti? Or are we just talking about *Dave's* rights, such as his right to like spaghetti if he wants to? In general: what state of affairs are we trying to create, and who are we threatening to shoot if they won't cooperate?

Comment: i have never raised any children to like spaghetti @gs and am not excusing murder

Comment: "mantained"? Cultures exist, change, disappear: there are historical processes. Do you mean that we have to set up a museum with a couple of Aztecs (found where?) eating human flesh?

Comment: practically @MauroALLEGRANZA i don't know precisely what i mean. do arguments for/against cultural homogeneity mean we should (not) listen to people that claim their culture has a right to exist, that they have a right to their culture, etc.

Comment: By deciding a culture is "harmful", you are taking a dictatorship or god position. Net benefit is very complex to measure, except if you are god. See my answer.

Comment: Cultures evolve, trying to preserve it in a particular state is likely to make it moribund.  Record it for posterity (if only so we can learn from it what not to do) and let it evolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ill-conceived: cultures have no rights. People have rights, at least in some cultures. If there's a culture out there that you object to, what can you do? Erasing a culture from outside is very hard if not impossible. You'd have to kill a whole lot of folks, thus becoming a human sacrificer yourself. Look at how the Brits, the Soviets and the US all tried to reform Afghan culture, and look at the result.

Comment: Rather than trying to murder the culture out of them, you could also try debating them, or showing them other cultures. Those may still not be super effective, but they're still options. Also, even killing oppressors (whether there is merit to this or not) would still be a long way from human sacrifice.

Comment: @NotThatGuy "you could also try debating them" Yes, and they could debate you, if they feel like it, but it won't be a question of "right to exist" then. It would just be a debate.  "killing oppressors (whether there is merit to this or not) would still be a long way from human sacrifice"  It's a slippery slope, from killing for an ideal, to killing for a god.

Comment: You could murder people *with the purpose of wiping out a culture*, or you can debate people *with the purpose of wiping out a culture*. Both would interfere with the hypothetical (non-existent) "rights" of a culture, while the former would also interfere with people's right to life and/or freedom (but at that point the question becomes whether them expressing their culture is interfering with the rights of others). "It's a slippery slope" - not really. Modern society maintains a separation between killing in the name of protecting oneself or others, and killing for other reasons.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I am afraid that arguing is not a very effective way to wipe out anything...

Comment: @NotThatGuy "Modern society maintains a separation between killing in the name of protecting oneself or others, and killing for other reasons." That sounds like Putin justifying the invasion of Ukraine or W that of Iraq.

Comment: "That sounds like Putin justifying the invasion of Ukraine" - it's also the justification for defending yourself from an armed intruder in your house... (but there are obviously a lot of differences between those 2 things.) In any case, I meant there's a separation between different types of killing on a local level in western countries. International law is a lot more fuzzy.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Imagine that where you live, some legislation in the future bans any and all genital mutilation of children, male circumcision included, out of concern for the child's pain. Do you think it will be easy to convince the Jewish and Muslim communities (assuming they exist in your country) to conform with this new law?

Comment: Genital mutilation of children is *a bad thing* (it's sad that this even a controversial statement in modern society). But whether it's viable or easy to make something illegal is a separate question entirely. (This may also complicated by the fact that many, but crucially, not all, of the affected believe their own genital mutilation was a good thing.) Do you think it was easy to convince slave owners to conform to the law banning slavery? Should we have kept that around just because banning it would've been hard?

Comment: @NotThatGuy Many people died for the abolition of slavery. Are you ready to die to save Muslim foreskins? I am not.

Comment: You have some odd objections. Whether people are willing to die to put a stop to something is independent from whether that thing is immoral and whether you should, if given the free option, grant others the right to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148492/discussion-between-olivier5-and-notthatguy).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is an interesting one, but perhaps not for the reasons you had in mind when posing it. A culture is a vaguely defined set of behaviours, traditions, values and beliefs associated with vaguely defined set of people, with both sets changing over time, so the first difficulty faced by the would-be maintainer of a culture is to define what the culture is. Given that cultures evolve, what version of a culture would you maintain? Would you suppose that a culture should be maintained in a frozen state, so that it does not change? If not, then how can you argue for any form of maintenance? How can you meaningfully distinguish between the natural evolution of a culture- which presumably you would accept- and any other form of cultural change? Western culture in the 1950s, say, included racism, sexism, teddy-boys, smoking, watching black and white TV, homophobia, etc etc etc. Are you saying that all those elements of culture should have been maintained? And which supra-cultural agency is it that you suppose should perform the role of the maintainer of cultures? By whose fiat are they empowered to determine which aspects of a culture are maintained and which should be allowed to evolve or wither?

Comment: i am not "saying" anything, as it's an innocent question

Comment: @prof_post and I wasn't really saying that you were saying anything - it was just a figure of speech. My overall point is that cultures are so inherently vague and unstable that the idea of maintaining them is unworkable.

Comment: yeah. you may be right, and i welcome answers along those lines. thanks!

Comment: @prof_post my pleasure, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not of our concern. *Natural selection* tends to preserve those cultures which have principles that are consistent with natural laws. This is a concern of nature.

If we decide to save information, or traditions of a specific culture, or we do not to keep cultures that make human sacrifices, we're being subjective, we're making judgements of relative and subjective value. The value of cultures is assessed by nature by natural selection, by elimination or preservation. Human sacrifice might be a positive act in multiple circumstances, you don't decide it, I don't decide it, it is nature that decides it.

In practice, if it is about "maintaining" my culture (that of the human group I identify with), I have the obligation to preserve it, and I should try to propagate it. If it is not my culture, I just forget about it, and in multiple cases, I might tend to hide and destroy it. This is very common. Hitler did not just wanted to kill jews, but moreover to destroy their culture.

You might argument that we should try to save information about old cultures or cultures that risk vanishing. Perhaps, yes, just for educational purposes. Learning alternatives is always useful, while forcing them in a group could produce unexpected results. Perhaps it brings benefits, perhaps it brings harm.

In general, groups tend to adopt traditions, procedures and habits from different cultures in a smooth, progressive and pacific way when they are consistent with their persistence and growth.

When you say a culture is "harmful", you are acting from a biased perspective. Hitler considered jews to be "harmful".

Probably the most ethical position is avoid trying to make changes in foreign cultures, and in our own cultures, except by means of personal change, which teaches and propagates by example. Each one of us has the right to harm himself, but not the others. If I want to create a cultural change which affects people, I should prove it affects in a positive way by applying it to myself in the first place. If I want to prove that communism is good, I should start by exerting the [*gift economy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_economy) by giving my own work.

Comment: Your position is that Hitler was wrong for trying to destroy culture, but you can also flip it around, and say that you shouldn't destroy Nazi culture, or that you shouldn't destroy a culture of slavery. Also, what makes a foreign *country* fundamentally morally different from a foreign *family* or even *person*. If your neighbour wants to whip and cage their children, who are you to destroy that culture? You can say you're subject to the same legal system, but that system needn't exist. Basically my point is that I don't think that's a good argument.

Comment: I didn't say Hitler was wrong or right. "who are you to destroy that culture"...?, I completely agree with that, that's exactly the point of my answer.

Comment: You seem to be taking an ethical position of non-interference. I was hoping pointing out some objectionable implications of that, but you didn't object (which is at least consistent, if nothing else). I'm curious: if *you* were the one being whipped and caged, would you prefer for your neighbour to put a stop to that, or to respect the "culture" of your assailant? If you practice or promote non-interference, that makes it more likely that others wouldn't interfere to help you either.

Comment: A huge misinterpretation. 1) It is not "non inference" but this: you can't consider yourself better than the others and take the right of changing their culture. 2) I do and must interfere with my culture as I've stated, you should read my answer. 3) For your question, if I'm the one that's whipped, I am a fool for remaining in such human so that happens. If I don't like a culture, I change groups. That's natural selection: weakening a "bad" (subjectively) group by leaving it and enforcing another group by integrating it.

Comment: You say "avoid trying to make changes in foreign cultures" - how is "non-interference" not a reasonable description of that? You're literally advocating to not interfere. Equality is the argument *against* your position: we are not "better" than the oppressor, we are equal to the victim, and we'd want them to liberate us if the we were in each other's shoes, and we do not deem the "right" to oppress to be a right that should be protected.

Comment: "if I'm the one that's whipped, I am a fool for remaining" - are you suggesting anyone suffering at the hands of another is a "fool" for not simply changing their situation? If you're locked in a cage, just stop being locked in a cage? I hope you're not suggesting that, but my hypothetical is very much about cases where you don't have much choice. "That's natural selection" - natural selection works by killing everything unfit. Not a great basis for morality. "you should read my answer" - you should read my comments, because no part relies on the idea that you won't protect your own culture.